# How can I reuse a unioned table in nested queries?

Tags: sql

I have a query that asks me to find the highest price among 3 types of products.

NOT USING ANY max or top function.

I am given 3 individual products table contains ID and price and other (not exactly same) attributes.
My thought was union 3 (SELECT id, price) tables together and select the one record that price> ALL.

```
SELECT tb1.model
FROM (
    SELECT model, price FROM pc
    UNION
    SELECT model, price FROM laptop
    UNION
    SELECT model, price FROM printer) tb1
    WHERE tb1.price>= ALL(
        SELECT price FROM(
            SELECT model, price FROM pc
            UNION
            SELECT model, price FROM laptop
            UNION
            SELECT model, price FROM printer
            )
        );
```

I was wondering is there a way NOT to repeat the UNION parts in the nested queries? Like now, I cannot use tb1 in the inner queries.

Comment: Hmmm . . . `min(- price)` comes to mind as simpler and fitting your requirements.

Comment: What is your restriction with not using `max` or `top`? Why can't you?

Comment: The restriction was: this is a question from my homework and my professor says NO.

Comment: CTE (`WITH foo AS ( <subquery> ) ...`) is the way to avoid repeating subquery in SQL.